# A few more graphic styling glitches

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

None of these are critical, just polishing stuff.

---

When breaking out the up/down votes on a post, the top number crashes into the separator line:

> [image: vote crash]

---

For some badges, e.g. taxonomy on the parent site, the list of users gets clipped at the right edge:

> [image: taxonomy clipped]

---

The the leading for the heading style in a post is too tight:

> [image: heading-style leading]

---

In a user's profile, on the activity page, the checkmark for accepted is clipped:

> [image: clipped check in user activity]

---

<s>There's also some strangeness with some links being blue and others red on the 10k tools page on the parent site, but I don't have a good screenshot of that.</s> (by-design)

Comment: 10k tools: Blue links are questions and red links are answers.

Comment: @KennyTM: That's what I'd originally been guessing, except that I could have sworn I was seeing a mix of red and blue in the highest/lowest answers section... now I'm just seeing the mix in the most X sections, which are a mix of Qs and As.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently these have been fixed, so we probably don't need this on the unanswered list anymore.  (I'm posting this because the question was just bumped by [Community](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).  Anyone who agrees with me can upvote either of the answers until at least one of them has a positive vote count.)

Answer (score 0):

http://i56.tinypic.com/2mweedv.jpg

there are two glitches in the image, so i ddnt need to post two images. the other glitch in the upper right corner.

Comment: it seems that the layout of this page has been corrected in the mean-time.